# Scan Objective-C code using HP Fortify in Windows OS

Tags: objective-c, security, code-analysis

I am trying to scan Objective-C source code using HP static code analyzer using command line. I have source code files with .m and .h extensions. Is there a way todo the scan on windows OS or do I have to move to MAC OS with Xcode installed on it?

Comment: Pretty sure that Fortify doesn't analyze Objective-C.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how exactly this software works? Do I have to install this software on my mac or have to upload my source code to Fortify web-portal. I am looking for Fortify static code analyzer for iOS application scanning.

Answer (score 0):

> ### About Objective-C Command Line Syntax
>
> The basic command line syntax for translating a single file is

sourceanalyzer -b  -clean

> sourceanalyzer -b  xcodebuild [compiler options]

where:

> > [compiler options] are options passed to xcode.

Can you please test it on Mac device.

Comment: i don't want to use MAC. Is there a windows based solution to it?

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how exactly this software works? Do I have to install this software on my mac or have to upload my source code to Fortify web-portal. I am looking for Fortify static code analyzer for iOS application scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on a Mac, because *sourceanalyzer* will need to run *xcodebuild* (see: command line syntax documented by other comments). And *xcodebuild* only runs on Mac OS. There is more to it than just scanning source code, as an analysis will also build the product, hence the need for Mac OS.